# Next.js onhover Link component gets refreshed

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am having an ecommerce application build in next.js. In this I have top bar contains contact and other link information, below that there is a long and search section. This two items are done in 2 components and both are combined.

Now the problem is, on hover any link in components, the particular page in refreshed (not reloading). What may be the problem. For better understanding I have placed a video blow. Please check.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tlh4e2os1ok2tpr/screen-recording.webm?dl=0

I have given all link as below,

```
<Link href="/" as="/">
    <a className="mr-4">Help Center</a>
</Link>
```

Please check my below codes,

`Top.js`

```
const Top = () => {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="topBar">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-6">
                        <p className="text-center text-sm-left">
                            <Link href="/" as="/">
                                <a>Sell in RangerBee</a>
                            </Link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <p className="text-center text-sm-right">
                            <Link href="/" as="/">
                                <a className="mr-4">Gift Card</a>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/" as="/">
                                <a className="mr-4">Help Center</a>
                            </Link>
                            <Link href="/" as="/">
                                <a>Download app</a>
                            </Link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Top;
```

`Header.js`

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="searchBar">
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row align-items-center">
                    <div className="col-8 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <p>
                            <Link href="/" as="/">
                                <a><img src="/vercel.svg" alt="Example" className="img-fluid" /></a>
                            </Link>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
                        <div className="menuCategory">
                            <p className="main" onClick={() => changeMenuCategory()}><span>Shop By Category</span> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronDown} className="ml-2 pt-1 fa-down"/> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} className="ml-2 pt-1 fa-bars"/></p>
                            <ul className={toggleCategory ? "main-nav" : "main-nav d-none"}>
                                {menus && menus.data.map((cat, index) => (
                                    <li key={index}>
                                        <Link href={"/products/"+cat.cat_slug} as={"/products/"+cat.cat_slug}><a title={cat.cat_name}>{cat.cat_name} <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} className="ml-2 float-right menu-arrow"/></a></Link>
                                        <ul>
                                            {cat.subcategory.map((subcat, index1) => (
                                                <li key={index1+index}><Link href={"/products/"+cat.cat_slug+"/"+subcat.sub_slug} as={"/products/"+cat.cat_slug+"/"+subcat.sub_slug}><a title={subcat.sub_name}>{subcat.sub_name}</a></Link></li>
                                            ))}
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-5 mt-3 mb-3 mt-md-0 mb-md-0">
                        <div className="search-box">
                            <div className="search-inner">
                                <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search for products, brands and much more" onClick={() => setToggleSearch(b => !b)} onFocus={(e) => trendingSearch(e)} onChange={(e) => startSearch(e)} />
                                <button><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch}/></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className={toggleSearch ? "search-result" : "search-result d-none"}>
                                <ul ref={dropdown}>
                                    {trending !== null && searched === null && trending.data.length > 0 && <li className="trending">Trending Search</li>}
                                    {trending !== null && searched == null && trending.data.length > 0 &&
                                        trending.data.map((trending, index) => (
                                            <li key={index}><Link href={"/products/"+trending.trending_slug} as={"/products/"+trending.trending_slug}><a>{trending.trending_name}</a></Link></li>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                    {searched !== null && searched.data.length > 0 &&
                                        searched.data.map((search, index) => (
                                            <li key={index}>
                                                <Link href={search.search_url} as={search.search_url}>
                                                    {search.images.length > 0 ?
                                                        <a><img src={api.IMAGE_PRODUCTS+"/"+search.images[0].image_name} alt={search.search_name} /> {search.search_name}</a>
                                                    :
                                                        <a>{search.search_name}</a>
                                                    }
                                                </Link>
                                            </li>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                        <div className="text-center text-md-right">
                            <div className="d-inline loginDrop">
                                <Link href={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/profile"} as={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/profile"}>
                                    <a className="signinBtn mr-5">{!isAuthenticated ? "Sign In" : "My Account"}</a>
                                </Link>
                                <div className={!isAuthenticated ? "login-content" : "login-content logout-content"}>
                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                    <div className="login-inner">
                                        <Link href={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/profile"} as={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/profile"}><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserCircle} className="mr-2"/> Your Profile</a></Link>
                                        <Link href={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/orders"} as={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/orders"}><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBoxOpen} className="mr-2 orderIcon"/> Orders</a></Link>
                                        <Link href={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/wishlist"} as={!isAuthenticated ? "/login" : "/wishlist"}><a><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="mr-2"/> Whishlist</a></Link>
                                        <div className="otherDrop">
                                            {!isAuthenticated ?
                                                <>
                                                <p className="first">Don't have an account?</p>
                                                <p className="register"><Link href="/register" as="/register"><a>Register</a></Link></p>
                                                <p className="login"><Link href="/login" as="/login"><a>Login</a></Link></p>
                                                </>
                                            :
                                                <p className="login"><a href="#" onClick={deauthenticate}>Logout</a></p>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <Link href="/cart" as="/cart">
                                <a className="cartBtn"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} className="mr-xl-1"/> Cart <span>{carts[0] === null ? 0 : carts.length}</span></a>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default Header;
```

`Layout.js`

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import * as Main from './Index'
import './styles/Index';

const Layout = ({ children, title }) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>{ title }</title>
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    </Head>

    <Main.Top/>
    <Main.Header/>

    <div>
      { children }
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

`next.config.js`

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass({
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        url: false
    }
})
```

Is there any problem with my code?

I am using sass for styling. What may be the issue. I have searched a lot and couldn't find any solution.  Actually am new to next.js. So I am not able to find a solution.

Comment: Can you provide a example that we can work through? Some example repo or somethiung like that

Answer (score 1):

As said in their docs, `next/Link` accept the props `href` and `as`, where:

`href`: The page that it should go for, this path will never change at runtime.

`as`: Something like a decorator, how the link should appears for the user. It can change in runtime.

Tha been said, lets take a look in one of yours Link's:

```
<Link href={"/products/"+trending.trending_slug} as={"/products/"+trending.trending_slug}><a>{trending.trending_name}</a></Link>
```

In this case your `href` is changing dynamic with your trending and it should be a page that exists in your project, like `pages/product/trending` and if trending is dynamic you can use `pages/product/[trending]` and then in the `as` property you should use the dynamic link, like you are already doing, `/products/"+trending.trending_slug`.

Take a look into their docs about it: https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes

Here is a issue that look's to be the same problem: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11157

Comment: Now 404 error solved. But the attached video is still not fixed.